# concrete5: link not working in editing mode

Tags: jquery, concrete5, c5

When I login to my site's CMS ([concrete5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete5)), the jQuery events won't fire anymore:

I've built a site where certain parts should be editable. There is just one HTML and through jQuery I display/hide parts on that site. It is all working, except when I login, the navigation does not work anymore. The funny thing: If I rightclick a navigation-element and open it in a new window, this link actually works.

[Page where the problem occurs](http://clients.alaingroeneweg.com).

It must be simple to solve, but not for me (completely new to concrete5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're loading your own version of jQuery in your template -- concrete5 already loads jQuery automatically so if you load your own as well it can cause conflicts.
There may be other problems as well, but try that first. Also, if you don't get your problems solved here on SO, you should try the concrete5 forums ( http://concrete5.org/community/forums ) -- people are pretty helpful there.